# USB communication between Android and PC without ADB

Tags: android, android-hardware

I just want to know is there a way to communicate between PC and Android device without the need of ADB.
Something like the Android device will become USB Host and read the data that PC send thought USB port.
Is it possible?

BTW I also want to ask is there any information in the latency when doing something like that. I need the latency lower than 15 ms.

Thank

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have the same plan...?